# Where can I get SO stuff?

Tags: support

since the StackOverflow shop is closed, I was wondering if it's still possible to somewhere get SO mugs, t-shirts, stickers etc?

By the way, why did they close the shop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They closed the shop because the amount of income it generated was't worth the effort involved in running it.

The people who were running it had "proper" jobs in other parts of the organisation and the store distracted them from those tasks.

You can still get stuff as prizes in competitions (the Windows 8 competition on Super User had T-Shirts as a prize for example).

Comment: Isn't there any other way to buy a mug for example? I tried searching on ebay, but I couldn't find anything...

Comment: Look out for a competition that has a mug as a prize?

Comment: Well I was thinking about getting a mug *not* in a competition, like buying it from __somewhere__.

Comment: just fyi, we have a webapps contest going right now [WebApps Second Anniversary Contest](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1250) /cc @Arnas